# nodejs - cannot search globally cant set headers

Tags: node.js

I try to implement a global search to all the schemas in database, to found doctors or hospitals.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Hospital = require("../models/hospital");
const Medico = require("../models/medico");

  app.get("/busqueda/todo/:busqueda", async (req, res, next) => {
  var busqueda = req.params.busqueda;
  var rex = new RegExp(busqueda, "i");

  try {
    let buscaHosp = await Hospital.find({ nombre: rex }, (err, hospitales) => {
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        hospitales: hospitales
      });
    });

    if (!buscaHosp) {
      res.json({
        ok: false,
        message: "No hospital."
      });
      return;
    } else {
      let buscarMed = await Medico.find({ nombre: rex }, (err, medicos) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
          ok: true,
          medicos: medicos
        });
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

busqueda.js

it throw this error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:469:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at Medico.find (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\server\routes\busqueda.js:38:32)
>       at C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4530:16
>       at process.nextTick (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4532:13
>       at process.nextTick (C:\Users\Leonardo Barahona\Desktop\angular-adv\restserver-adminpro\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Comment: it's because you're setting the response twice `res` variable the general error message **Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client** is usually due to already finishing the request.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are setting the response twice

it will always be set in

```
 let buscaHosp = await Hospital.find({ nombre: rex }, (err, hospitales) => {
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        hospitales: hospitales
      });
    });
```

instead you should build up a return object by having a function scope variable named `response = {}`;

and do `response = await Hospital.find({ nombre: rex }, (err, hospitales) => {});`

where the return value is

```
return {
  ok: true,
  hospitales: hospitales
};
```

same thing for the other cases just set this variable to the correct value, then at the end of the function simply run `res.status(200).json(response);`